# How do i show that functions are closed under addition

Tags: linear-algebra

So... I'm doing a question for practice and I'm just stuck.

$E$ is defined as the space of real valued even functions
$V$ is defined as the vector space of real valued functions

$E \subset V$ vacuously.

So I need to show that $E$ is a subspace of $V$.
I have no problem showing the zero function is an even function.
But I'm having some problems with the deduction of 'Closure under Addition'

Taking $\space f,g \in E$, I need to show that $f+g \in E$

I need to show that $\forall x\in \mathbb R, (f+g)(x)=(f+g)(-x)$

I'm stuck here. My notes just say $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ but why is this so?

Comment: What is $W$? ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat sorry it supposed to be $E$. I've changed it

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of function addition.

Comment: Oh. so it applies to all functions?

Comment: Yes, it is a very general definition.

Comment: Does it follow that $(cf)(x) = c(f(x))$ where $c \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Danxe That is in fact the definition of $cf$.